# I have 2 expressions which should be valid that are not recognized as such

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

cards1 = "'F'*4 + 'H'*10"; cards2 = 'FFHH'
def find_number_of_cards(cards):
    regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<FandH>[FH]+) | (('F')[*](?P<F>[0-9]+)\s*[+]\s*('H')[*](?P<H>[0-9]+))")
    result = regexp.search(cards)
    if result == None:
        return ("The expression given is not valid.")
    else:
        FnH = result.group('FandH')
        F = result.group('F')
        H = result.group('H')
        if FnH == None:
            return F, H
        else:
            return "Blank."

print(find_number_of_cards(cards1))
print(find_number_of_cards(cards2))
```

Comment: What's the definition of card -> no one can help in wirtting reg-ex without knowing what is a card. What is the expected output of `find_number_of_cards(cards1)` and `find_number_of_cards(cards2)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<FandH>[FH]+) | (('F')[*](?P<F>[0-9]+)\s*[+]\s*('H')[*](?P<H>[0-9]+))")
```

to this:

```
regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<FandH>[FH]+)|(('F')[*](?P<F>[0-9]+)\s*[+]\s*('H')[*](?P<H>[0-9]+))")
```

It's looking for a space in the string, which isn't there.